# Error VSCode Undefined function 'sqlsrv_connect'. en la Consola

Tags: javascript, sql, html5, datatables, php7

NO entiendo este error, soy nuevo en la programación he aprendido de forma autodidacta y he realizado todos los cambios que sugieren a este error pero sigue apareciendo

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.xxx.xx.xx"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
;
//  if( $conn ) {
//       echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
//  }else{
//      echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
//      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
//  }

?>
```

incluso modifique el archivo php.ini
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente no tendrás habilitadas las funciones de sqlsrv activadas.
Ves a la configuración del Visual. Pon esto en el buscador "@ext:bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client" y busca abajo la opción de stubs.
Agregar elemento: sqlsrv y pdo_sqlsrv.

Comment: Exelente explicación, solo que al principio no encontraba la parte de la configuración, para el futuro, esto se encuentra en: Archivo -> preferencias -> Configuración. Saludos.